# Is there a way to add permissions to a file that prevents it from being uploaded anywhere?

Tags: files, permissions

Is there a way to add permissions to a file that prevents it from being uploaded anywhere?

I'm researching a way of making a file format that isn't uploadable. In the age of security I think it's impressive to have such a thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If a file can be read, it can be uploaded anywhere. Root in Linux/Unux can read all the files despite their permissions. You can patch the kernel to limit the root capabilities but then the file becomes unreadable by everyone. Then the attacker can boot from his own media/OS and read your file regardless.

Probably you need encryption. The file still can be read and uploaded but without the decryption key it's pretty much random noise.